# Full Page Screenshot with Selenium python in IE

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, internet-explorer

I am trying to take a full page screenshot on Internet Explorer using Selenium.

Looking through the Options.py code from selenium/webdriver/ie I found these lines:

```
class Options(object):

KEY = 'se:ieOptions'
SWITCHES = 'ie.browserCommandLineSwitches'

BROWSER_ATTACH_TIMEOUT = 'browserAttachTimeout'
ELEMENT_SCROLL_BEHAVIOR = 'elementScrollBehavior'
ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION = 'ie.ensureCleanSession'
FILE_UPLOAD_DIALOG_TIMEOUT = 'ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout'
FORCE_CREATE_PROCESS_API = 'ie.forceCreateProcessApi'
FORCE_SHELL_WINDOWS_API = 'ie.forceShellWindowsApi'
**>>FULL_PAGE_SCREENSHOT = 'ie.enableFullPageScreenshot'**
IGNORE_PROTECTED_MODE_SETTINGS = 'ignoreProtectedModeSettings'
IGNORE_ZOOM_LEVEL = 'ignoreZoomSetting'
INITIAL_BROWSER_URL = 'initialBrowserUrl'
NATIVE_EVENTS = 'nativeEvents'
PERSISTENT_HOVER = 'enablePersistentHover'
REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS = 'requireWindowFocus'
USE_PER_PROCESS_PROXY = 'ie.usePerProcessProxy'
VALIDATE_COOKIE_DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'ie.validateCookieDocumentType'
```

...

```
@property
def full_page_screenshot(self):
    """ Returns the options Full Page Screenshot value """
    return self._options.get(self.FULL_PAGE_SCREENSHOT)

@full_page_screenshot.setter
def full_page_screenshot(self, value):
    """
    Sets the options Full Page Screenshot value

    :Args:
     - value: boolean value

    """
    self._options[self.FULL_PAGE_SCREENSHOT] = value
```

However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use these. Any help would be appreciated. Or if you may have any other tips for taking a full page screenshot on IE would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Does `driver.save_screenshot("path to save \\screen.jpeg")` work for your use case?

Answer (score 1):

I use `maximize_window()` to full size the browser window, then use `save_screenshot()` to take the screenshot. You can refer to the code sample below. It works well in IE 11:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://www.google.com/" 

driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path='IEDriverServer.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
driver.save_screenshot("C:\\your\\path\\filename.png")
```

Please note to change the path to your owns.